# Azure SQL Managed Instance Drop/Deletion Event logs

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-sql-managed-instance

We have an Azure SQL Managed Instance having number of databases on it . We have to enable audit logs of SQL Managed Instance from diagnostic settings and also enabled logs by executing queries on MI and sending those logs to event hub. We are getting up logs (select, Execute) but not able to see the logs related to database drop/delete activity

the blog (https://docs.imperva.com/en-US/bundle/cloud-data-security/page/78051.htm) I am using the for enabling audit log in Azure SQL Managed Instance
plus we need to see/visualize the data/request that are coming to eventHub.

[image]

Comment: Select "Diagnostic settings" from the left-hand menu.
Click on "Add diagnostic setting" or select an existing one to edit.
Enable the "AuditLogs" category and select the desired destination, such as Azure Storage, Event Hub, or Log Analytics.
Save the diagnostic settings.

Comment: for more details refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=ingestion)

Comment: [Audit](https://i.imgur.com/FTzjnJV.png), [here](https://i.imgur.com/IdPuHoc.png)

Comment: Create a new alert rule using this [reference](https://docs.datadoghq.com/security/default_rules/azure-activity-log-alert-delete-azure-sql-database/). Hope this helps

Comment: will this rule/alert createUpdateSQLServerFirewallRule will triggered when any of the database is delete from subscription?